# Google searches my old website contents not current content

Tags: seo, asp.net, iis, migration

I have my web application named like `www.example.com`. I used this website over 3 years. Now I have moved my website `www.example.com` in a virtual directory as its new path is `www.example.com/myweb`.

When I search my content on Google it displays my old website path which is now moved.

- old path was: `www.example.com/vision/myvision`
- new path is: `www.example.com/Myweb/vision/myvision`

Comment: Google search optimization: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fwebmasters%2Fdocs%2Fsearch-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf&ei=f4EoUoy6B5OThgfz5oCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNF_d-m7vBwh9cfYhs5r7B1ABzCq4A&bvm=bv.51773540,d.Yms&cad=rja

Answer (score 3):

Since Google has indexed the URL of your old website, you have to do URL re-writing to catch the old URL and redirect it to your new URL.

Since I have hosted an application `example.com` then all pages inside the `example.com` like `example.com/index.html` had been index by Google.  When I configured our web site to open with `www.example.com` then I have to write the rule in the *web.config*:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" >
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: can you explain your points...

Comment: Please go through updated answer

Comment: i have used rewriting from https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/ article but it has no url rules like your.. what can i do..

Comment: which iis version you are using

Comment: I have used iis 7

Comment: go to the following link http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00470/0/Installation-of-native-URL-Rewriting-module-URL-Rewrite-for-IIS7.html

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading the sitemap using Google Webmaster Tools. It will re-index all your URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If your old path scheme does not conflict with the new one, you can serve both pages and tell Google that `/vision/my-vision` should actually be `/posts/vision/my-vision`, by

1. redirecting `/vision/my-vision` to `/posts/vision/my-vision`, or
2. [using canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) on `/vision/my-vision` pointing to `/posts/vision/my-vision`.